# How do I call `grabFixture()` method from within `ApiTester instance in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception, fixtures

I am building an API in Yii2 2.0.14 and running tests with Codeception. Examples in the tutorial* show that I can call fixtures like so:

`$profile = $I->grabFixture('profiles', 'user1');`

However this doesn't seem to be available in my test class here:

```
<?php 

namespace frontend\tests\api;

use frontend\tests\ApiTester; 

class DemoCest
{
    public function _fixtures()
    {
        return [
            'users' => [
                'class' => UserFixture::className(),
                // fixture data located in tests/_data/user.php
                'dataFile' => codecept_data_dir() . 'user.php'
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function demo(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $users = $I->grabFixture('users');

        $I->wantTo('perform actions and see result');
        $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        $I->sendPOST('/user/test', ['name' => 'davert', 'email' => 'davert@codeception.com']);
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK); // 200
        $I->seeResponseIsJson();
        $I->seeResponseContainsJson(['message' => 'test OK']);
    }
}
```

I have seen that you need to add fixtures to `frontend/tests/api-suite.yml` but Codeception is throwing an exception when I do that

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: tests in
>   /var/www/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php on
>   line 389

I am completely lost.

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
enabled:
    - Yii2:
      part: [orm, email, fixtures]
    - \frontend\tests\Helper\Api
    - REST:
        url: http://securedata.test/api/v1
        depends: PhpBrowser
        part: Json
```

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

- tutorial - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-test-fixtures.html

Comment: What kind of error that you got after enabling the config at `frontend/tests/api-suite.yml`

Comment: The error is `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: tests in /var/www/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php on line 389
`

Comment: share you full Suite configuration.

Comment: hey did the answer helped you out in solving the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Add to your suite configuration, you haven't defined the `tests` path in the `codeception.yml` under `paths`.

If you look into the line the error points to it will take you to the line inside the `matchSingleTest` function

in your case

```
list(, $suite, $test) = $this->matchTestFromFilename($suite, $config['paths']['tests']);
```

in which it gives `tests` as `undefined index` for the `$config['paths']` array, which if you backtrack parses the `codeception.yml` to the `$config`,

You are using an older version of `Yii 2.0.14` which may have the missing section from the `execute()` see this [**`ISSUE`**](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/4432)

So add `tests` directory as `.` and make sure your `codeception.yml` is in the `/tests` root.

see the following

```
 paths:
     tests: .
```